# scope resolution operator semantics

Tags: c++, class, scope

1) What is the use of the scope resolution operator in cases like the following, when we can also define it inline?

```
class Box
{
   public:
      double length;      // Length of a box
      double breadth;     // Breadth of a box
      double height;      // Height of a box
      double getVolume(void);// Returns box volume
};

double Box::getVolume(void)
{
    return length * breadth * height;
}
```

2)
Also, the semantics of the line `double Box::getVolume(void)` is confusing. why couldn't it have been: `double getVolume(void)::Box` . Is there some history behind this ?

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question? Define the operator inline?

Comment: Do you mean what is the difference between defining the function only in the class, or in the class and separately in a source file?

Comment: by inline , i meant : defining the function INSIDE THE CLASS. @awesomeyi

Comment: Short and quick answer. It compiles faster to put the function body in the source file, instead of in the header file.

Comment: `double Box::getVolume(void)` is consistent with every other use of the operator. The scope is `Box` and the thing in the scope is `getVolume`. Thinking "`Box` contains `getVolume`" is just as easy as thinking "`getVolume` belongs to `Box`", so I don't see how one is more confusing than the other. Of course `Box` doesn't even have a `getVolume` function in its scope in your example.

Comment: i'm just defining the function outside the class :/ @Brian ..did you mean "the question" dowsn't make any sense ?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: put the function declaration in the class without a body.
then you can implement the body out side.

Comment: @DimaMaligin, A definition without a body is an oxymoron. It's then a declaration.

Comment: maybe because it isn't the full code ? it's just the definition of the class . @NeilKirk

Comment: @guitar_geek, If that's "just the definition of the class", it's still missing `getVolume`.

Comment: @chris noted and edited.

Comment: As you've discovered, sample code which doesn't compile, doesn't elicit a positive response here.

Comment: sorry. my bad. should have included the definition . that was a mistake. please don't downvote my question for that @everyone  :/

Comment: Pro-tip: make the function `double getVolume() const`

Comment: @NeilKirk ..this is just a copied example from a website. I was just trying to find out, are there any cases where defining the method outside the class can be useful .

Comment: Yes, I mentioned previously.

Comment: Also it is needed for a circular dependency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) What is the use of the scope resolution operator in cases like the following, when we can also define it inline?

In your example, the scope resolution operator is not required when defining a method inside a class:

```
class Box
{
   public:
      double length;      // Length of a box
      double breadth;     // Breadth of a box
      double height;      // Height of a box
      double getVolume(void)// Returns box volume
      {
         return length * breadth * height;
      }
};
```

However, when a function is defined outside of a class, the programmer needs a method to associate a function with a given class.  This method needs to differentiate class methods from freestanding functions.  Thus the scope resolution operator.

> 2) Also, the semantics of the line double Box::getVolume(void) is confusing. why couldn't it have been: double getVolume(void)::Box . Is there some history behind this ?

Actually, the syntax is not confusing when you consider the declaration syntax of a freestanding function:

```
return_type function_name(function_parameters);
```

The encompassing namespace or class is associated with the function name, so the syntax is:

```
return type class_name::function_name(function_parameters);
```

The definition and declaration may be less confusing if you arrange the pieces differently:

```
double
Box ::
getVolume(void)
{
  return height * length * depth;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the question. Now that i read it again afters so many years, as pointed out in a comment, even my brain hurts